# Is possible to research all the normal technologies in Surviving Mars?

Tags: surviving-mars

In Surviving Mars technologies are sorted randomly on each game, my question is if you can always research all of them or you only have a random number of them.

Note that I'm not talking about breakthrough technologies, I know that they are limited per game.

Comment: @Wrigglenite, why did you erase the last part of my question? In fact, that was my main concern that I wanted to ask about, because I use mods.

Comment: You can see the details of an edit by clicking on the "edited x ago" button.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can always research all 100 technologies. The order is different based your starting coordinate, but you always end up seeing all 100.

Breakthroughs are different though, and the set of breakthroughs you get are random each game and will be a subset of the available 55 breakthroughs.

> Research is used to unlock new technologies, structures, other opportunities that provide additional options for the colony. There are 100 regular technologies and 55 breakthroughs in the game.
>
> Technologies are divided among 5 tech trees and the breakthrough list. Tech tree technologies normally have to be researched in a specific order randomized at the start of the game. Breakthroughs are obtained through Anomalies and can be researched in any order. Mystery and Story Bits technologies are also shown in the Breakthrough tree.
>
> All technologies have a range of positions where they can appear in the tech tree. The range is increased by the Tech Variety Game Rule and Chaos Theory makes every tech tree position valid for all technologies. The order of technologies is determined by the map coordinates so starting in the same location will create the same order for technologies.